# making a php variable equal to a radio button

Tags: php, html, css

So what I am trying to do is making a radio button = to a php variable. So when someone clicks on the radio button and press continue they will get their pick on the website.

What I've tried:

```
<form action="./game/index.php" method="post">
    <label id="coin1" class="coin1">
        <input type="radio" name="coin" value="<?php echo $pick; ?>"/><?php echo $pick; ?>
        <?php echo $ct; ?>
    </label>
    <label id="coin2" class="coin2">
        <input type="radio" name="coin" value="<?php echo $pick; ?>"/><?php echo $pick; ?>
        <?php echo $t; ?>
    </label>
    <button id="next">Create a Game</button>
</form>
```

This is what I found when google-ing it but it doesn't really seem to work

this is what I used on the other site:

```
<div id="player1">
    <a href="#"> <img class="img-square" src="<?php echo $steamprofile["avatarfull"]; ?>">
    <b><?php echo $steamprofile["personaname"]; ?></b><b class="caret"></b></a><br>
    <?php echo $pick; ?>
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="player2">
    <a href="#"> <img class="img-square" src="<?php echo $steamprofile["avatarfull"]; ?>">
    <b><?php echo $steamprofile["personaname"]; ?></b></a><br>
    <?php if ($pick == $ct) {
        echo $t;
    }else {
        if ($pick == $t) {
            echo $ct;
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Both coins have the same value? (being `$pick`)

Comment: @SourceOverflow yes I am not sure how to do this but I was showing what I've tried, please correct me on this if you know how to do it in another way (the right way ;P)

Comment: How are you planning to differentiate between the two selections if both of them represent the same value?

Answer (score 0):

To read the value into php you would need to use the $_POST variable. In ./game/index.php:

```
$coinvalue = $_POST['coin'];
```

However the coins should have different values so you can tell which was selected.